# Why Can I add a reference to a .Net library in ms access 2013?

Tags: vba, ms-access, dll, qr-code, com-interop

I needed a library to create QRcodes in ms access 2013 and I found this one.

http://en.code-bude.net/2013/10/17/qrcoder-an-open-source-qr-code-generator-implementation-in-csharp/comment-page-1/#comment-101119

It's under MIT license so is convenient.
I tried using the sample code provided by the author in Visual Studio C# and It worked fine. But I can't add the reference in Access 2013 W 8.1.
I've tried to add the reference trough the VBA editor In Tools>Reference then browse for it.
Is there a way to get around this problem?

Comment: Because it is .net and it does not have com interface.

Comment: Is there a way to get around this problem?

Comment: You can create a com interface wrapper for this library.  See this article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29783350/expose-c-sharp-class-through-com-interop

Comment: @Jules Could you add it as an answer? Ill accept it

Comment: All good, I don't think this warrant an answer :)

Comment: Add a Link xD https://whoisburiedhere.wordpress.com/2011/07/12/creating-a-com-object-from-scratch-with-c/ this might help someone