# SMO library on Delphi

Tags: delphi, smo

I'm using SQL Server 2017. Is there any way to use the SMO library in Delphi (FMX)?

The official documentation shows how to use this library from Visual Studio: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/installing-smo?view=sql-server-2017#smo-nuget-package
, which I have actually done.

10x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to create a dll (or a COM server dll/exe) in Visual Studio exposing the required features of SMO and use this dll (or COM server) from Delphi.

Comment: So far so good but would be more useful with some how-to instructions, as the typical Delphi user may not be familiar with this kind of task in VS.

Comment: @MartynA: This will get you started:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/exposing-dotnet-components-to-com

Comment: Thanks a lot. There are many tutorials about creating new dll, but is there any tutorial where I can learn to create a Dll from an existing one? I did not find anything. I need that because it's my first time in doing this

Comment: @plionut you don't need to create a dll from an existing one. Create a new dll and use the SMO library from that one and expose the new dll to COM. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29783350/expose-c-sharp-class-through-com-interop

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @plionut if you are happy with the answer please accept it :-)